# Arithmetic Properties when finding Determinants of Distinct Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For example,

if $\det(A) = \begin{vmatrix}{}
a & 1 & d \\
b & 1 & e \\
c & 1 & f\end{vmatrix} = -2$ and $\det(B) = \begin{vmatrix}{}
a & 1 & d \\
b & 2 & e \\
c & 3 & f\end{vmatrix} = -3$

find k for $\det(C) = 
\begin{vmatrix}{}
a & -1 & d \\
b & 0 & e \\
c & 1 & f\end{vmatrix} = k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice by cofactor expansion using $\det(A)=-2$ and $\det(B)=-3$ respectively:

$$\left|\matrix{b & e\\ c & f}\right| - \left|\matrix{a & d\\ c & f}\right| + \left|\matrix{a & d\\ b & e}\right| = -2$$

$$\left|\matrix{b & e\\ c & f}\right| - 2\left|\matrix{a & d\\ c & f}\right| + 3\left|\matrix{a & d\\ b & e}\right| = -3$$

Adding $-2$ times the first to the second we get

$$-\left|\matrix{b & e\\ c & f}\right| + \left|\matrix{a & d\\ b & e}\right| = 1$$

Now using cofactor along the same column of $C$ we get

$$-\left|\matrix{b & e\\ c & f}\right| + \left|\matrix{a & d\\ b & e}\right| = k$$

So $k=1$.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense but is there any way to solve the problem in terms of our knowledge about the effect of elementary row or column operations on the determinant? For example, the property that forming a matrix B by multiplying one column of A by k (where k is not equal to zero) gives us det(B) = (k)det(A)

Comment: The matrices are not row or column equivalent (specific values of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ would determine that, but we do not know them). If you knew in advance there was a solution not dependent on other entries (as we now do know) you can pick convenient values which make $A$ and $B$ row equivalent to $C$

Answer (score 0):

Expand all the determinants along the second column. You'll get $x -y +z = -2$, $x-2y+3z=-3$ and $-x+z=k$, where $x=det(b,e;c,f)$, $y=det(a,d;c,f)$, $z=det(a,d;b,e)$. Multiply the first equation by 2, and subtract it from the second equation.